# To find zeros of the given complex polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to find the four zeros of the polynomial $z^4 + 4$, one of them being $z° = 2^2 \exp (i \pi/4) = 1+i$. Then use those zeros to factor $z^4 + 4$ into quadratic factors with real coefficients.

I am not getting what is meant by zeros of the polynomial, the first principle root being given, I guess it is asked to find the remaining roots.

They are: $-1+ i$, $-1-i$, $1-i$.

If I am right, then how can I use these zeros to factor $z^2 +4$ into quadratic factors with real coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

The complex zeros of a real polynomial (not polygon) come in [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) pairs, where the real parts are the same and the imaginary parts are negatives.  In your case $\overline {1+i}=1-i$ If you multiply the two factors that are conjugate, you get a real result:  $(x-a-bi)(x-a+bi)=(x-a)^2+b^2$, which is real if $a,b$ are.